# How to add new row to datagridview on the cell click event of the same datagridview?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

How to add new row to datagridview on the cell click event of the same datagridview
with same content of the previous row.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a mousedown event for the datagridview to get the row number clicked

```
private void userGrid_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    rowClicked = e.RowIndex;
}
```

Then, create a click event that adds the row with the values from the previous row. Continue adding parameters for each column you want to add.

```
string column1 = queueGridView.Rows[rowClicked - 1].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
string column2 = queueGridView.Rows[rowClicked - 1].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

queueGridView.Rows.Insert(rowClicked, column1, column2);
```